# Using visual virtual machine for profiling

Tags: java, profiling, visualvm

I have a simple java program containing not more than 10 method calls. I want to profile it using visual virtual machine. Pl note that i am using linux. I try to do the same by following command.

```
sh visualvm_134/bin/visualvm & java cased/test/MainController
```

I tried with command as below also.

```
java cased/test/MainController & sh visualvm_134/bin/visualvm
```

but it does not show my application "MainController" in the visual virtual machine. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong ? I am new to profiling and visual virtual machine.
I tried using visual VM with jibble miniwebserver and it showed me reasonable profiling results. but how do i use it with java program?

Thanks.

Comment: How long does your application typically last when you start it? It might have finished running before visualVM can find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can not profile an application startup with VisualVM.

Use [NetBeans Profiler](http://profiler.netbeans.org/) instead, which is based on the same engine as in VisualVM but allows you to profile the application startup as well.